# How to use dplyr to edit subset of rows based on relative location?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have election data where two of the elections fail to differentiate between the contest for Treasurer at the state level and the contest for County Treasurer. Data is presented like so:

```
> elections
# A tibble: 13 x 6
    year election contest   data              party number
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>
 1  2010 general  Treasurer Registered Voters NP       628
 2  2010 general  Treasurer Times Counted     NP       320
 3  2010 general  Treasurer Times Blank Voted NP         4
 4  2010 general  Treasurer Times Over Voted  NP         0
 5  2010 general  Treasurer Scott K. Summers  G         15
 6  2010 general  Treasurer Dan Rutherford    R        245
 7  2010 general  Treasurer Robin Kelly       D         51
 8  2010 general  Treasurer James Pauly       Lib        5
 9  2010 general  Treasurer Registered Voters NP       628
10  2010 general  Treasurer Times Counted     NP       320
11  2010 general  Treasurer Times Blank Voted NP        38
12  2010 general  Treasurer Times Over Voted  NP         0
13  2010 general  Treasurer Rebecca C. McNeil R        282
```

Lines 9-13 should be "County Treasurer," as most years are. The data is by precinct so manually editing the data would be a pain.

Both of the years that have this issue, Rebecca C. McNeil is the only candidate, so it's easy to identify where the rows I need to change are and use `mutate` to fix the contest associated with the candidate.

```
library(dplyr)

> elections %>% 
+   mutate(contest = case_when(
+     str_detect(data, "Rebecca C") ~ "County Treasurer",
+     TRUE ~ contest))

# A tibble: 13 x 6
    year election contest          data              party number
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>            <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>
 1  2010 general  Treasurer        Registered Voters NP       628
 2  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Counted     NP       320
 3  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Blank Voted NP         4
 4  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Over Voted  NP         0
 5  2010 general  Treasurer        Scott K. Summers  G         15
 6  2010 general  Treasurer        Dan Rutherford    R        245
 7  2010 general  Treasurer        Robin Kelly       D         51
 8  2010 general  Treasurer        James Pauly       Lib        5
 9  2010 general  Treasurer        Registered Voters NP       628
10  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Counted     NP       320
11  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Blank Voted NP        38
12  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Over Voted  NP         0
13  2010 general  County Treasurer Rebecca C. McNeil R        282
```

But I need the 4 preceding rows to also have "County Treasurer" for the contest, with desired output as:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 6
    year election contest          data              party number
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>            <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>
 1  2010 general  Treasurer        Registered Voters NP       628
 2  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Counted     NP       320
 3  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Blank Voted NP         4
 4  2010 general  Treasurer        Times Over Voted  NP         0
 5  2010 general  Treasurer        Scott K. Summers  G         15
 6  2010 general  Treasurer        Dan Rutherford    R        245
 7  2010 general  Treasurer        Robin Kelly       D         51
 8  2010 general  Treasurer        James Pauly       Lib        5
 9  2010 general  County Treasurer Registered Voters NP       628
10  2010 general  County Treasurer Times Counted     NP       320
11  2010 general  County Treasurer Times Blank Voted NP        38
12  2010 general  County Treasurer Times Over Voted  NP         0
13  2010 general  County Treasurer Rebecca C. McNeil R        282
```

I've been thinking I could possibly do this through adding row numbers and using them for identification but I haven't figured out how to make that work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider cleaning the representation logic in your data overall.  For example, it looks like your `data` column has a mix of candidate names (matched by `party`) but then also other variables, like `Times Counted`.  Like you did one big pivot to move a bunch of columns into a name/value long form.  This makes it difficult without another column that keeps track of each election (e.g. `election_index` which has a unique value per year/election/contest).  Just a thought - otherwise you are left with the more brittle approach of editing by counting backwards from certain rows.

Comment: Also - it'd be helpful if you can provide `dput` for your example data, rather than only pasted output.

Comment: Why not do another case_when based on `party` variable: `mutate(contest  = case_when(party == "NP" ~ "County Treasurer", TRUE ~ "contest")?

Comment: @andrew_reece unfortunately the format is how the county provides it so I don't really have a choice. And I didn't know about `dput` but I see what it does now which makes a lot of sense and I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can add a row index and count back from the target row with edits.

```r
# example data
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = c(rep("election_A", 9), "election_B"), b = letters[1:10])
df

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   a          b    
   <chr>      <chr>
 1 election_A a    
 2 election_A b    
 3 election_A c    
 4 election_A d    
 5 election_A e    
 6 election_A f    
 7 election_A g    
 8 election_A h    
 9 election_A i    
10 election_B j   # <-- anchor row for updating previous rows
```

Now count back from the `'election_B'` row and update the values in column `b`:

```r
lag_ct <- 4
target <- "election_B"
new_label <- "foo"

df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(b = if_else(rowid >= rowid[a == target] - lag_ct, new_label, b))
    
# A tibble: 10 × 3
rowid a          b    
<int> <chr>      <chr>
1     1 election_A a    
2     2 election_A b    
3     3 election_A c    
4     4 election_A d    
5     5 election_A e    
6     6 election_A foo  
7     7 election_A foo  
8     8 election_A foo  
9     9 election_A foo  
10   10 election_B foo
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using `case_when` because I needed to use `str_detect` and `if_else` didn't like me using a formula.

Comment: Except that when I try doing it on all elections (or even a single year imported separately) I get a warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" and the results don't line up. I understand what the warning is telling me but I don't understand why I would be getting it in this situation. I realize without the data you can't know what the issue specifically is.

Comment: Try to narrow down to which part of your data is throwing the error, then see if you can reproduce it with representative example data.  Just doing that may help you figure out what's different about that part of your data - and if not, post the new example data and error as a new post here on SO, it'll be a lot easier to help you that way.